# Memcpy after socket receive not working

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to send an array of a structure through a TCP socket by sending it as an array of bytes(char*), and then turning it back into a the original structure type on the receiving end.

The structure contains the data of a photo and is like this:

```
struct photo{    //List that will store photo information
  uint32_t id_photo;
  char *file_name;
  struct keyword * key_head;
  struct photo * next;
};
```

Then I send it like this:

```
photolist p_list[photocount];//Photo count = nº of elements to be sent
for(int i = 0; i<photocount; i++){
    p_list[i]=*aux;
    p_list[i].key_head = NULL;
    aux = aux->next;
}
//Sending list of photos to the new peer
buff = malloc(sizeof(photolist)*photocount);
memcpy(buff, p_list, sizeof(photolist)*photocount);
nbytes = send(fd, buff, sizeof(photolist)*photocount, 0);
```

Finally i receive it like this(the amount of elements of the array is previously received sucssefully):

```
 buff = (char *) malloc(sizeof(photolist)*photosize);
    nbytes = recv(sock_fd_server, buff, sizeof(photolist)*photosize, 0);
    if(nbytes == -1){
      perror("Reciving");
      exit(-1);
    }
    photolist testlist[photosize];
    memcpy(testlist, buff, sizeof(photolist)*photosize);
```

However, when i try to print of of the elements of the structure after receiving it, a segmentation fault happens. I have done a print of the buffer before sending and after receiving, just to see if the data is the same, and it was, so i have no idea, what I'm doing wrong. 
Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: If I read correctly: "Some code I'm not showing you crashes. Here is some some comunications code that may or may not have anything to do with the problem"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided definition of photolist
But If you are sending a structure like

```
struct photo{    //List that will store photo information
  uint32_t id_photo;
  char *file_name;
  struct keyword * key_head;
  struct photo * next;
};
```

from client to server and accessing `file_name` at server it will not work as file_name contains address from client program it is not valid in server program

Comment: Oh, of course, how stupid of me! Thank you very much, and sorry for such a stupid mistake!